# When the following hook 'wp_ajax_' is executed?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to understand the codebase of a custom wordpress plugin. However it is not clear when exactly the following hook get invoked.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wcsmartcod_json_search_categories', array( $admin_class, 'ajax_search_categories' ) );
```

I know that 'wp_ajax_' hook only fires for logged-in users. But is it invoked as soon as a user logged in ? Is it called only once for a logged-in user ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the JS, it'll have a trigger that calls the ajax function 'wp_ajax_wcsmartcod_json_search_categories'. i.e. ajax doesn't just fire on its own.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Thanks.